# Flash AS3; how to play an entire animation then stop

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, side-scroller

I'm currently trying to make an 'attack' animation. However has to have a cool down (of about 2-3 seconds).

Whilst I can get it to do that, the problem I'm currently having is that the animation cuts out. What I am after is the animation to play in full, then the countdown timer begins.

I tried using a custom dispatch event. However because the objects are placed into arrays. I tried following some suggestions elsewhere, but none seemed to work. I either got the error `"A term is undefined and has no properties"` if I tried adding the event listener straight after I pushed the objects into the array (IE enemies[i].addEventListener(...))

Or I got the error `"addEventListener is not a function"` if I tried adding the listener as a variable of the object (IE enemy.addEventListener(...);)

I have also tried more simpler methods using while loops (the AI makes an attack, that triggers the while loop, incrementing an integer until it hits 100 or so, then it exits and resets to 0. During the while loop, the boolean whether the AI/character can attack is false. When it exits, it resets to true also) But the problem with this was, it cut the animation off.

If there are any suggestions on how to go about making a simple Cooldown on attack speed, please do help. I'veposted the sections of the program I believe are relevant (involving creating the enemy and pushing it, how the AI determines if it attacks, and the sections involving the attack etc);

```
public function addEnemies()
    {
        enemies = new Array();
        var i:int = 1;
        while(true)
        {
            attackDone = cooldown(i);
            if(gameLevel["enemy"+i] == null) break;
            var enemy = new Object();
            enemy.aI = true;
            enemy.mc = gameLevel["enemy"+i];
                            //....
                            //OTHER VARIABLES
                            //....
            enemy.attackAnimation = new Array (26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40)
                            //....
            enemy.animStep = 0;
                            //....
                            //....
            enemy.attack = false;
                            //....
            enemy.cooldown = 0
            enemy.canAttack = true;
                            //....
                            //....
            enemy.addEventListener("ATTACK_DONE", attackDone);
            enemies.push(enemy);
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Determine what the AI does;

```
public function moveEnemies(timeDiff:int)
        {
            for(var i:int = 0; i<enemies.length; i++)
            {
                //Move the enemies
                moveCharacter(enemies[i], timeDiff);

                enemies[i].playerDistance = player.mc.x - enemies[i].mc.x;
                if(enemies[i].playerDistance < 0)
                {
                    enemies[i].playerDistance = -enemies[i].playerDistance;
                }

                //If hit something, reverse direction
                if(enemies[i].hitWallLeft)
                {
                    enemies[i].moveLeft = true;
                    enemies[i].moveRight = false;
                    enemies[i].attack = false;
                }
                else if(enemies[i].hitWallRight)
                {
                    enemies[i].moveLeft = false;
                    enemies[i].moveRight = true;
                    enemies[i].attack = false;
                }

                if(enemies[i].playerDistance <= 10)
                {
                    enemies[i].moveLeft = false;
                    enemies[i].moveRight = false;
                    if(enemies[i].canAttack)
                        enemies[i].attack = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

Perform the attack;

```
public function moveCharacter(char:Object, timeDiff:Number)
        {
            if(timeDiff < 1) return;


                            //.......
                            //.......
            //Key Press
            var horizontalChange = 0;
            var newAnimState:String = "stand";
            var newDirection:int = char.direction;

            //Test Assumptions
            //Move Left             

                                    //.......
                                    //.......

                //attack
                if(char.attack)
                {
                    newAnimState = "attack";
                }


                       //.......
                       //.......
                       //.......
                       //.......
                       //.......
                       //.......
                       //.......
                       //.......
                       //.......
                       //.......

            //Set new position of Character
            char.mc.x = newX;
            char.mc.y = newY;
                       //.......
                       //.......
                       //.......

            char.animState = newAnimState;
                       //.......
                       //.......
                       //.......
                       //.......

            else if(char.animState == "attack")
            {
                char.animStep += timeDiff / 60;
                if(char.animStep > char.attackAnimation.length)
                {
                    char.animStep = 0;
                }
                char.mc.gotoAndPlay(char.attackAnimation[Math.floor(char.animStep)]);


            }

                       //.......
                       //.......

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`addEventListener` must be called on an `EventDispatcher` - a class than can dispatch this event that you are waiting for.

You try to call it on a simple object:

```
var enemy = new Object();
enemy.addEventListener("ATTACK_DONE", attackDone);
```

That's why you get this error. You should create your own custom class that can dispatch this event.

And also, as you start your animation, there is no place that you dispatch it. It should be either on the last frame of your movie, or you should do some code in order to know when the animation is over (look for frame labels; set timer; dispatch event on key frame, or whatever you like).

Comment: Hey thanks, yeah I have a dispatchEvent on the last frame of the animation. I'll give it a shot :)

Comment: Then the easiest way to try is this: `enemy.mc.addEventListener` IF `mc` is where you have `dispatchEvent`. Try this, then if you need you can create a class :) Cheers!